# Is there any way to controll the keyboard leds of Gigabit Saber 15G (Clevo N850HK)?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, backlight

I recently intalled ubuntu in my laptop (Gigabyte Saber 15G a copy of Clevo N850HK) and I can't control the keyboard leds. I tried use xset and some solution for clevo laptosps of github like 
https://github.com/ejcosta/clevo-keyboard-backlight

https://github.com/gamaral/clevo-wmi

and nothing.
Is there any form to find the exact moudule that controll the keyboard light?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking with people on github, they showed me [this](https://github.com/tuxedocomputers/tuxedo-keyboard). And it works fine.